# WYSIWYG wiki, no need to enter wiki syntax

Tags: linux, wiki, wysiwyg, self-hosted

I like to use wikis for internal documentation a lot. But I don't like the *Edit › Save › See-Result* cycle.

Some days ago I stumbled over CKEditor, an open source WYSIWYG HTML editor, and was impressed.

Now I hate the *Edit › Save › See-Result* cycle, and want a "better wiki".

Features I need:

- A wiki-like system.
- WYSIWYG (I don't care if the internal format is HTML or a markup language, or if WYSIWYG is realized by integrating CKEditor).
- Easy cross-linking between pages.
- Other users should see what I typed after I saved the page. The *Edit › Save* cycle is ok.
- Self-hosting on own Linux server.

Can someone give my a software recommendation?

Comment: Would a Wiki with auto-preview (think of writing a question/answer on any SE site) also fit your needs – i.e. one where the preview is separate from the input field, but still doesn't require you to hit a preview/save button to see what it looks like? Alternatively, "any Wiki" where you can integrate ckeditor?

Comment: @Izzy good question. I guess I don't want to edit ASCII any more. With CKeditor I am able to copy+paste HTML tables. I guess this is not possible with a markup-language which provides a live preview. Your second question: Yes, I guess any wiki which does support chkeditor should work.

Comment: Install a wiki, or host it in a wiki farm, and install extensions. You'll get exactly what you need.

Comment: @Quidam your comment is too abstract for me. Which particular wiki does provide the needed features?

Comment: All the Wikis. A wikis is a software. You host the software on your own site, or you subscribe to a solution where the software is already hosted. Example of wiki softwares are Mediawiki, moinmoin, etc. You can complete functionality with extensions, the same way that you complete functionalities in your browser with extensions.